# How can I redirect to another page after I post data to my database?

Tags: node.js, express, post

I have a form and I'm inserting information into the database. That part works perfectly fine but how do I redirect to another page after that?

```js
app.post('/create', function (req, res) {
        Room.findOne({'name' :req.body.name}, function(err,room){
            if(err){
                return done(err);
            }

            if(room){
                return done(null,false,req.flash('this room name is taken'));
            }else{
                var newRoom = new Room();
                newRoom.name = req.body.name;
                newRoom.topic = req.body.topic;
                newRoom.participants = req.body.participants;
                newRoom.type = req.body.type;
            }
            newRoom.save(function(err){
                if (err){
                    throw err;
                }
                redirect: '/home';
            })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_writehead_statuscode_statusmessage_headers) to review http.Response API for nodejs. 
response.writeHead(statusCode[, statusMessage][, headers])

replace this line

```
redirect: '/home';
```

with the following

```
res.writeHead(302,{
            'Location':'/path',
        });
        res.end();
```

The status code for redirecting is 3xx level, 302 in the example is for 'found'
The 'Location' header will give the path to redirect to

If written in Express, reference [here](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html) and use

```
res.redirect([statusCode,] '/path')
```

if optional status code is not explicitly expressed, it will be 302 'found' by default

Answer (score 2):

With **Express** you can use `res.redirect()` method. For full documentation [click here](http://expressjs.com/pt-br/api.html#res.redirect).

In your case, replace:

```
redirect: '/home';
```

With the following:

```
res.redirect(301, '/home');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
res.redirect(pathnam)
```

by default it will sends the 302 status code, 
or you can pass the status code as the first parameter

```
res.redirect(301, pathname)
```